# Set Linux date with ddmmyy

Tags: linux, date

I need to set the date of a Linux box with a string I get from a program. This string is formatted as ddmmyy. Is it possible to use that directly or do I need to reformat it first?

Currently I have tried the following without any luck:

```
 date +%d%m%y -s "071012"
```

**This should be 7. Oct 2012** but it is interpreted backwards and then becomes 12. Oct 07.

If I try to tell date to use the reverse format:

```
date +%y%m%d -s "071012"
```

it will still read it as 12. Oct 07. I would rather not have reverse the string because I thought date would be able to take care of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` set the **output** format only. You need to pre-format your string is you want to use the `-s` option (either by modifying your program or by using e.g. `sed`).

In your case, you can pipe the result of your program in this:

```
sed -e "s/\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\\3\\2\\1/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the date in a shell variable, and you could set the date like this:

```
dt=`your_program`
date -s "${dt:4:2}${dt:2:2}${dt:0:2}"
```